# Shippable + AWS ECR : Push image - no basic auth credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, shippable-ci

In my shippable, I configure the integration to AWS ECR with the Aws_access_key_id and Aws_secret_access_key copied from the IAM user created in AWS  with the policy AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess. But when I run the build, the error is,

```
Post https://623575552266.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v2/creditcard_server_dockerimg_rep/blobs/uploads/: no basic auth credentials
```

Any idea?

Regards
Hammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the "docker push" from post_ci to push in yml file helps to solve the issue, as the command is running inside of the container for the former. [Push an image to ECR](http://docs.shippable.com/integrations/imageRegistries/ecr/)